# Beliefs on the chronology of Mahabharata

Tags: mahabharata, belief, history

Many scientific studies have been done on the chronology of the *Mahabharata*. [This](http://www.omilosmeleton.gr/pdf/en/indology/narahari01.pdf) research paper uses astronomical data  mentioned in the *Mahabharata* to establish that the events of the *Mahabharata* happened around *3000 BC* (nearly *5000* years ago).

Although, many people believe that *Mahabharata* might have happened millions of years ago. My question is this: Is there any scriptural basis of these beliefs?

Comment: Nearly everyone believes that Mahabharata happened around 5000 years ago. It is **Ramayana** which is said to be millions of years old.